# Что с файлом archive-product.php в woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Скопировал файл archive-product.php в папку с темой. theme/wocommerce/archive-product.php

Мне нужно было при выводе товаров определенной категории вывести блок с сообщением. 
Я как понял этот файл отвечает за вывод товаров при просмотре категории.

Добавил код. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но изменений не произошло.

Удалил файл и папку в папке с темой. Пошел напрямую в папку плагина. Вставил там. Тоже ноль реакции.

Что не так?